# Unable to upvote/ downvote while reviewing triage

Tags: bug, triage, google-chrome

I'm able to see voting buttons but unable to upvote/ downvote the questions while reviewing them in a **Triage** queue only. Using Google Chrome v71.0.3578.98

[image]

Comment: You'll have to provide additional details. Can you provide screenshots? What happens exactly when you click on those buttons?

Comment: Unfortunately, my triage queue is been over for today. But to simply elaborate, no action happens when we click on upvote/ downvote buttons.